# How to provide executing function object instance to a callback in Javascript

Tags: javascript, websocket, callback, dom-events

I have a namespace object on which I have defined some functions. One of the functions is used to create a websocket session to a remote server.

```
ns.Session = function(url, config, callback){
   var ws = new WebSocket(url);
   ws.onmessage = function (e){
       if(login(e.data)){
           // This is the point at which I need to pass back the session object to callback
           callback(session):
       }
   }
   ....
}
```

In Javascript, as far as I know if someone invokes this function using `ns.Session(....)` then the `this` object will be ns. So, how do I get the **instance** of the "session" to send to the callback.
`arguments.callee` is deprecated as far as I know.

The whole reason I am doing it this way is that the session is not considered "usable" till the server confirms the login, so I don't want to prematurely return the function object before it is actually connected and logged in. Hence the use of a callback. If there is a better way to achieve this, I am open to that too.

Session has a bunch of other inner functions like `addHandler`, `sendData` etc which I have not shown here for sake of brevity.

Comment: By instance of the "session", do you mean `ws` variable?

Comment: No, the Session object itself, i.e. the function. If I were to pass ws to the callback then it will break the encapsulation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use pointer to function like this:

```
ns.Session = function session(...) {
    // 'session' here points to your function, so you do
    callback(session); // like you wrote
    callback(ns.Session); // same effect if you don't change ns and ns.Session pointers
}
```

Also, I don't see why you use the word "instance" in this case, because functions have only one instance. If you call it with the 'new' keyword, function creates new object from the function, and now there you can use "instance" word.

Comment: So if I call the ns.Session(...) multiple times will it not create new session object each time? Basically I wanted to create multiple sessions and each time a session got created, the callback would get that "instance" of the session.

Comment: I am new to javascript, maybe I am doing it completely wrong? Should I be using an object literal or something here?

Comment: No, you have to call it like that then:
var someOnj = new ns.Session(...);
And in this case, 'this' will point to created object, rather than 'ns'.

Comment: hmmm... Since user of this function may not invoke it with new, how is this kind of thing done in javascript world? Using another function like SessionFactory to ensure that a new session is always created?

Comment: It is one way to go, you can do something like that: `ns.SessionFactory = function(..) { return new ns.Session(..) }`